# How does one undo a git revert from remote?

Tags: git, github

So, I merged an old branch, `test`, from remote that was a pull request into a project and it made the project stop working. Then, while still in remote I went back to the merge and selected "revert" to bring it back to working again. Unfortunately, the old remote branch, 'test', states that it is now "3 commits" behind and the code from that branch will not compare on the GitHub GUI with the `master` branch.

Should I just make a new copy of the old branch, "test", that has already been merged, and do a new Pull Request after fixing the error ? I tried everything on local and the test branch has all the changes I want still. Thank you.

Comment: I think we might need to see a branch diagram to understand what is going on here.  Also, when you went back to remote and did a revert, did that remove the merge commit, or just make a new commit to undo the merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset your master to last working commit with minor complication that all other users who have latest checkout of master branch should be running following two commands [As git history have changed for the master branch].

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

And the step to set your branch back to original state are below:

```
$ git reset HEAD~n --hard 
$ git push origin master -f
```

replace `n` above with no. of commits you want to remove from head. `-f` is to force push as now local master tree is different from remote master.

I have done it many times and it always works :)